# Iexfinance API to Excel

Tags: python

I'm trying to stream Live Quotes using the IexFinance API, keep in mind this is my first coding attempt. I've managed to be get the stock quote prices through python but I'm unsure how I would get that data then onto Excel.

From my understanding I would need to get this data into a csv file in order to export that into excel. I've tried adding the code df.to_csv('stock.csv') but I get the error 'StockReader' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

```
import pandas as pd
from iexfinance.stocks import stock
batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
batch.get_price
df.to_csv('stock.csv')
```

Comment: where have you created the dataframe? What does the guidance say about stockreader object?

Answer (score 0):

General pointer: Looks like you need to read into df variable first.

This line:

```
Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
```

According to the [guidance](https://pypi.org/project/iexfinance/) returns a dataframe

So:

```
df = Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
```

Or, as you have now discovered:

```
df = batch.get_price
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me, I changed my last text from batch.get_price to df=batch.get_price and it seemed to work. Now i'm just unsure as to how to constantly get the quotes on excel to be streaming (or updating by themselves. Would I need to add a sort of loop function through Python?

Comment: Sounds like you are after a timed loop

Comment: That's what I figured I've added the following code which seems to loop the run csv every 5 seconds or so. However it doesn't seem as seamless as streaming quotes on other websites. There seems to definitely be a 15-30 seconds delay on excel when I refresh. Is this normal? Code: 
#loop
starttime=time.time()
while True:
batch=Stock(['amd', 'tsla'], output_format='pandas')
df=batch.get_price()
df.to_csv('stock.csv')
time.sleep(0.05-((time.time()-starttime) % 0.05))

Comment: Probably worth posting a new question to get as much input as possible.